# Error on deploying Next.js on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, next.js, grpc

I was hosting my Next.js web app with SSR on AWS Amplify, until one day I was getting error 503.

[image: The error I got one day out of the blue]

Digging in the AWS console, I came across a CloudWatch log for the lambda function that handles the SSR part of the app.

```
2021-12-02T19:40:49.972Z    1bb29425-4acf-44aa-aabb-ba5afa558512    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module '@grpc/grpc-js/package.json'\nRequire stack:\n- /codebuild/output/src947501987/src/focalpick-client/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs",
"code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
"requireStack": [
    "/codebuild/output/src947501987/src/focalpick-client/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs"
],
"stack": [
    "Error: Cannot find module '@grpc/grpc-js/package.json'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /codebuild/output/src947501987/src/focalpick-client/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs",
    "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)",
    "    at Object.578847 (/var/task/chunks/559.js:500372:34)",
    "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)",
    "    at Object.526541 (/var/task/chunks/962.js:2299:22)",
    "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)",
    "    at Module.778514 (/var/task/chunks/962.js:2021:20)",
    "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)"
]}
```

The error says that it cannot find module `@grpc/grpc-js`. It seems that this is a package that Firebase uses internally. I tried installing the package in my repository, re-deployed the Amplify app, but this wouldn't help. Trying to deploy a clean next app worked though.

All the issues and questions I've read didn't help me find a solution.

Comment: What version of the firebase SDK are you using? This seems to be an issue introduced in version `9.5.0`, see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5752. I'd suggest downgrading for now until a fix is released.

Comment: @juliomalves thanks for the prompt to the issue. I suppose it's firebase's problem after version 9.1.0.. but i don't want to downgrade back to v8.. mehh

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found out that firebase currently has issue with version 9.2.0 and up when deploying on cloud providers like AWS.

My temporary solution is to downgrade back to `firebase@9.1.0` until the issue is fixed.

The github issue that helped me figure out is this: [[9.5.0] Error: Cannot find module '@grpc/grpc-js/package.json' in electron](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5752#issuecomment-986187787)

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me on next@12.0.9, After testing many many things, I just downgraded the version to next@12.0.8 and it started working.

Comment: Good to hear that. As mentioned above, my problem was firebase.